# custom nav walker breacks when loading

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom bootstrap nav walker. Added a loader. But when I load the site the nav and header seems break for a millisecond. after that site loads correctly. I have no idea what is the issue. I am using xamp in my local host. If you see the screen shot you will find that the menu is broken for a second and also the spinner is moving from left to right a bit when loading. For better view I made the screen shot slow gif. Please help me.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIWYi.gif)

Comment: Hello.. Please spare 5 minutes to take [this tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to ask a productive question in this community. You need to provide a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your source code. Then we might be able to have a look into it and see what the problem is..

Comment: I am really sorry for my mistake, But I have no idea what would be the problem is. Should I provide my nav walker and header file code?